# Как в django сформировать динамическую строку запроса в шаблоне?

Tags: django

Есть некая страница со списком статей основанная на ListView
Я добавил несколько блоков гиперссылок, для сортировки и вывода статей например:

**Блок 1**
Подробно|Кратко

**Блок 2**
За день|За неделю|За месяц

**Блок 3 (количество статей на страницу)**
10|20|50

Параметры вывода передаю в строке запроса:

```
article/?sort=table&pag=10&date=week
```

я попробовал сделать через

```
@register.simple_tag
def dinamic(value, str_filtre, str_value):
```

формируя в шаблоне что то вроде:

```
<a href="{% url 'article:list' %}{% dinamic request.get_full_path "sort"        "list" %}">полно</a>|
```

но не выходит золотая рыбка... параметры задваиваются при нажатии два раза на одном блоке, например (по дате):

```
article/?sort=table&pag=15&date=week&date=month
```

подскажите способ формирования таких ссылок. Бросьте пример.. Буду благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно [создать шаблонный тег](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) такого вида:

```
@register.simple_tag
def url_params(name, value, params=None):
    url = '?' + name + '=' + value
    if params:
        qs = '&'.join(p for p in params.split('&') if p.split('=')[0] != name)
        url = url + '&' + qs
    return url
```

И использовать его в шаблоне так

```
<a href="{% url 'article:list' %}{% url_params 'sort' 'table' request.GET.urlencode %}">
    подробно
</a>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Вроде работает